# Looking for react google map component to find location by name

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I am currenlty building an app where I have a list of countries.
I was wondering if there was a Googlemap react component available that allows us to find places by their names and not by lat and lng (to avoid making an api request to find them)

Seems that you can only use lat and lng params with the following :

react-google-maps, google-map-react , google-maps-react

As usual , thanks guys :)